# How to make prettier sort my imports in the following order?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

This is what i have now:

```
  "importOrder": ["^react(.*)", "use", "^components/(.*)$", "<THIRD_PARTY_MODULES>", "@/(.*)", "^[./]"],
```

And what i wanna do is the following:

*everything from react goes first*

*then hooks*

*then goes third party libs*

*then components*

*then components from the ui folder*

*and only then goes like images, svgs, so in general all from imports ./*

How to do that kind of a thing? I'm just bad at regexps, cause in most cases to get the desired regexp you just gotta google it.